# ember-data many to many relationship deleteRecord not working

Tags: ember.js, many-to-many, ember-data, delete-record

Using ember-data, I try to delete a record in a many to many relationship.

I have a player and lobby object. A lobby has 1 owner and many players. A player can be owner of many lobbies and member of many lobbies.

My model:

```
App.Lobby = DS.Model.extend({
    title : DS.attr("string"),
    owner : DS.belongsTo("App.Player", {
        inverse : "ownedLobbies"
    }),
    players : DS.hasMany("App.Player", {
        inverse : "joinedLobbies"
    })
});

App.Player =  DS.Model.extend({
    username : DS.attr("string"),
    ownedLobbies : DS.hasMany("App.Lobby", {
        inverse : "owner"
    }),
    joinedLobbies : DS.hasMany("App.Lobby", {
        inverse : "players"
    })
});
```

In my LobbyController and PlayerController, I do:

```
  Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    doDelete : function (model) {
        model.deleteRecord();

        model.one("didDelete", this, function () {
            this.transitionToRoute("index");
        });

        model.get("transaction").commit();
    }
});
```

didDelete triggers nicely, so the transition does happen..
When record gets deleted, for example a player:

- Any lobby which has that player as owner will delete the player in its owner list. (so successful one to many relationship)
- **Any lobby which has that player as just a member, will still show the player, but with all properties set as cleared (username blank, ..). (so failed many to many relationship)**

This is the same when deleting a lobby, so, if a lobby gets deleted:

- Any player which is owner of that lobby will delete the lobby under its list of "owned lobbies" (so successful one to many relationship)
- **Any player which is a member of that lobby, will still have that lobby under its "joinedLobbies", but with all properties set as cleared (title blank, ..) (so failed many to many relationship)**

When trying to delete that blanked record, I get the following error:

> Attempted to handle event `deleteRecord`
>   while in state rootState.loading. Called with undefined

I cannot find any solution to this problem on the internet. Many mention the fact that ember-data is still bugged, but this looks like a common use of the ember store. Did I overlook something?

Thanks in Advance.

*(Editing a player or lobby does update the object correctly everywhere. So this only appears when deleting a record.)*

Comment: what kind of backend stack do you use? and more importantly, how does your backend respond to the delete actions?

Comment: We don't have backend yet. We use ember fixture adapter at the moment.